# Selected Index Change on WPF combobox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, selectionchanged

I'm converting an app of mine from WinForms to WPF.  I came across this problem where in WinForms if I CLEAR a combobox, that does not fire combobox.selectedindexchange.  It only fires when the user actually changes the index.

That's the functionality I need.  However in WPF I can only find combobox.SelectionChanged.  This unfortunately fires on both index change and clearing a combobox (any change).

In WPF how can I only trigger an event when the user changes the index?  I'm assuming there's a solution I'm missing that's like the WinForms solution.  I'm trying not to play games with global variables and having to track what was previously selected....that's a mess.

Mouseleave is also a mess.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can implement in `SelectionChanged` event:

```
Private Sub OnSelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Dim combo = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)


    If combo.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        'do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So go ahead and fire the event, but ignore all code if the combobox is empty.

Well, that's certainly easy enough!  It's not like I have thousands of items so there wouldn't be a performance hit.

Thanks Rafal!  Sometimes I think about things too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove event handler, invoke clear method and add again event handler.

Example code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="myCB"                   
              SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
         <ComboBoxItem>test1</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>test2</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>test3</ComboBoxItem>
     </ComboBox>

     <Button Content="Clear" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow class:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Selected index: {0}", CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        RemoveHandler Me.myCB.SelectionChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChanged
        Me.myCB.Items.Clear()
        AddHandler Me.myCB.SelectionChanged, AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChanged    
    End Sub
End Class
```